# Is a[n] really interchangeable with *(a+n) - why does sizeof return two different answers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a problem understanding one thing in C. I've read in "ANSI C" that statements like `a[n]` where `a` is array are really equivalent to `*(a+n)`. So here's a small code snippet I've written to check that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int *p = a;
    printf("sizeof a: %d\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("sizeof p: %d\n", sizeof(p));
    return 0;
}
```

After executing the code the program outputs:

```
sizeof a: 40
sizeof p: 8
```

I don't understand - what did I just do? How are `a` and `p` different objects? (Judging by the output of sizeof function)

Comment: array is not pointer, it decays to pointer at some circumstances, but not in case of `sizeof`... there a lot of similar questions here with perfect answers

Comment: `%d` requires an argument of type `int`. To print a `size_t` value, such as the result of `sizeof`, use `%zu`.

Comment: The syntax `a[n]` is defined to be the same as the syntax `*(a+n)`. Neither syntax is shown in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 **The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand**,
>   which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The
>   size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an
>   integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type,
>   the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and
>   the result is an integer constant.

So object `a` defined as an array of 10 integers occupies a memory extent that has size of 40 bytes because each element of it in turn has size of 4 bytes (that is in your environment sizeof( int ) is equal to 4).

```
int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Object `p` is defined as a pointer and initialized by the address of the first element of the array `a`

```
int *p = a;
```

In the environment where you compiled the program size of pointer is equal to 8 bytes.

You can consider declaration

```
int *p = a;
```

also like

```
int *p = &a[0];
```

Comment: A question about one of the sentences from this C standard snippet:
`If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated`, what does it mean for a name of array to be "evaluated"?

Comment: @qiubit  The size of a VLA is determined at run time. VLA(s) have automatic storage duration and their sizes are determined each time the code block where they are defined gets the control. It is the meaning of the term "Variable Length Array".:)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the *expression* `a[n]` is equivalent to `*(a+n)`. But that's not relevant to your code sample.

You've defined `a` as an array object consisting of 10 `int` objects, and `p` as a pointer object of type `int*`. The equivalence you mention means, for example, that the expressions `a[5]` is equivalent to `*(a+5`; both are `int` expressions with the value `5`. But neither expression appears in your code.

You've defined `a` and `p` as objects of different types, and there is no rule in C that says these objects are interchangable. `sizeof a` is equivalent to `10 * sizeof (int)`, and `sizeof p` is equivalent to `sizeof (int*)` (the size of a pointer to `int`).

One special rule that your program does depend on is that an expression of array type is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's initial element. In:

```
int *p = a;
```

`a` is an expression of array type. It's converted to the equivalent of `&a[0]`, and that pointer value is used to initialize `p`. Thereafter, `a` and `p` are equivalent *in most contexts*; they both refer (one indirectly, one directly) to the address of the initial element of the array object `a`. But the operand of the `sizeof` operator is one of the contexts in which this conversions does not take place; `sizeof a` yields the size of the array object, not the size of a pointer.

All this is explained very well in section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).